# How to get the Dock to open the Documents and Download folder in Finder?

Tags: finder, dock

When I click on the Documents or Downloads folder in the Dock, a Grid comes up.  Is there a way to get it to just open in the Finder?  Instead of having to click on Documents and then click on Open in Finder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right-click or Control+click on the Documents folder in the Finder, and click 'Make Alias'.

You probably want to move the alias somewhere else and rename it "Documents". Then, drag the Documents alias into the Dock.

Voíla, a link to the Documents folder instead of a Documents folder stack.

Comment: Worked, but a real hack. Apple should add this feature, as an option.

Comment: I disagree—it's a perfect extension of the Mac's existing UI metaphors. Users are provided the option without Apple needing to outright clutter up Preferences with an additional switch.

Answer (score 8):

In MacOs High Sierra, you can just option+command+click the Documents folder in the Dock to open its content directly.

Comment: I could verify this behavior as far back as Mavericks (10.9), but [this article](https://www.macworld.com/article/1142863/106stacks.html) suggests it should work from 10.6 onwards.

Answer (score 4):

1. Hold  <kbd>CMD</kbd>  while clicking the Documents or Download folder on your dock. It will open up your home directory with Documents or Download folder highlighted.
2. Press  <kbd>CMD</kbd> +  <kbd>O</kbd> to open.

Or right click on the folder on dock, select "Open Documents"

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single key command from Finder.

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>L</kbd> 
alternatively, it's in the Go menu if you want to keep your hand on mouse/trackpad.

Answered here as it's linked as a dupe from [How can I open my Downloads folder in one click?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/409311/how-can-i-open-my-downloads-folder-in-one-click) which asks for an alternative keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly quicker way would be right-click or control-click on the dock icon and select "Open 'folder name'".

I do wish "Open in Finder" was at the beginning of the stack/fan for easy access though.