# How can I open my Downloads folder in one click?

Tags: finder, dock, alias

How can I open my Downloads folder in one click?

Downloads are my most important folder because that's where the new files go. Yet, it is the *only* folder I can't make an alias for, meaning I can open it in a single click from my dock or home screen.

What success looks like:
Opening the Downloads folder in one click (A keyboard shortcut would be fine too).

Here's what hasn't been working:

- Using spotlight to search for my Downloads (slow)
  -right clicking Downloads in my dock and then opening the folder from there (2 clicks)

Since I open my Downloads folder so many times per day, I really want a way to open it in one click.

Note: Somebody already came up with a neat solution [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290491/how-to-add-a-shortcut-to-open-a-new-finder-window-to-the-launchpad-or-dock), but it unfortunately brings ALL finder windows that might be open to the front, which is not really wanted behavior.

Comment: I dropped a keyboard shortcut answer into the linked duplicate. Note: Bringing Finder to the front **should** bring all Finder windows with it. That's traditional behaviour, which has actually been slightly broken since about High Sierra.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the **Downloads** *stack* in the **Dock**, you can **⌘-click** it to open a new **Finder** *window* to the **Downloads** *folder*.

If you want to create an **AppleScript** *application* to put in the **Dock** that when *single clicked* opens a new **Finder** *window* to the **Downloads** *folder* bringing it to the top without bringing other **Finder** *windows* to the top also, then the follow line of **AppleScript** *code* is all that's needed to be saved as an **AppleScript** *application* and placed in the **Dock**:

```applescript
do shell script "open $HOME/Downloads"
```

If you want it to always be in the same location on the screen and set to a particular view and size, you can use information in my answer in question you linked in your OP.

Example:

```applescript
do shell script "open $HOME/Downloads"
tell application "Finder" to ¬
    tell window "Downloads" to ¬
        set {current view, toolbar visible, bounds} to ¬
            {list view, true, {1475, 871, 2499, 1360}}
```

---

**Notes:**

- If the **Downloads** *folder* is already open it will just bring it to the front without bring  other **Finder** *windows* to the front also.
- If you close the **Downloads** *folder* it will bring other **Finder** *windows* to the front and this is the default behavior and has nothing to do with having opened the **Downloads** *folder* with this *script*.